# Python - How to search for entries in a panda dataframe based on entries (list) in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and dataframes. I have a big panda dataframe I need to extract information from, I will try to explain my problem in a small example.
Say my dataframe looks like this:

```
 name   city   number
 Hana   NYC    23
 Fred   London 12
 Ben    Paris  90
 Lisa   Berlin 3
```

Now I have a list with entries that relate to the column "number"

```
numbers = [3,12,23]
```

and I want to have the corresponding entries in another list from the "name" column

```
names = ['Lisa', 'Fred', 'Hana']
```

Is there an existing function for this problem?

Comment: Look up .loc[] and .isin(). Also your list of names should be strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not explain your desired output, but:

If you want to filter by one of the cirteria:

```
df[df['number'].isin(numbers)]
```

will leave you with rows within the numbers array.

If you want both:

```
df[(df['number'].isin(numbers)) & (df['name'].isin(names))]
```

Don't forget the names array to strings:

```
names = ['Lisa', 'Fred', 'Hana']
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right I should have expressed it more clearly. I meant that I want to search with the numbers list in the dataframe and get the names list as an output. I used this new_df = df[df['number'].isin(numbers)] and then new_df['name'].values.tolist() and got my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df.number.isin(numbers)].name.tolist()
```

and, if you want exactly in same order:

```
df[df.number.isin(numbers)].sort_values("number").name.tolist()
```